# Swift 5.1 UIWebView Does not View URL because of untrusted Certificate

Tags: swift

I have a webview that I want to display an internal website where there's an untrusted cert. How can I view bypass the cert check and display the website correctly.

Error Messages:
default TLS Trust evaluation failed
TLS Trust encountered error
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1202

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable transport security. [More details here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
```

Also, **UIWebView** deprecated, use **WKWebView** instead

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it still does not work.